# Speed up difference of two images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, difference

I have two images as numpy array, each is 180x180 and have R,G,B values which is total of 97200 individual values. I am traversing each pixel and each R,G,B; calculating the difference between corresponding two pixels and summing up to an integer. It takes approximately 5 seconds. How can I speed up the procedure?

Comment: This seems like a prime thing GPUs are faster at doing. Or for a smaller boost, you can try multithreading.

Comment: You have plenty of libraries to do either, multithreading built in, and for numpy + gpu you have CuPy

Comment: how about directly `(array1 - array2).sum()` without traversing pixels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy` you can do it directly

```
result = (array1 - array2).sum()
```

You can also calculate only in one direction

```
result = (array1 - array2).sum(axis=0)

result = (array1 - array2).sum(axis=1)

result = (array1 - array2).sum(axis=2)
```

On my old computer for image `800x600` it takes about `0.003` second.

---

Example with `cv2` which gives image as numpy array

```
import cv2
import time

img1 = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')

print('shape:', img1.shape)

start = time.time()

result = (img1 - img2).sum()

end = time.time()

print('result:', result)
print('  time:', end-start)
```

---

**EDIT:** numpy array with image may use data type `uint8` which can use only values `0..255` so substraction `1-2` may gives `254` instead of `-1`. You may convert data to `int` to get negative values and `-1` instead of `254`. And then you can use `abs()` or `**2` to convert negative values to positive to create correct sum - like in [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

```
print(img1.dtype, img1.dtype)

img1 = img1.astype(int)
img2 = img2.astype(int)

diff = img1 - img2
print( diff.sum() )
print( (diff**2).sum() )
print( np.abs(diff).sum() )
```

and all these calculations still are fast.

Comment: I added information about `uint8` which can be used by numpy array.